# Should advance testing setup be committed?

Tags: railstutorial.org

The instructions for the 'advance testing setup' at the end of chapter 3 (3.7) of the book online suggest to checkout to the master branch before making changes.

Would not be convenient to add and commit these changes with `git add -A` and `git commit -m`? I am wondering whether there is some reason for these commands to be omitted at this stage, or they are supposed to be implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there where no good reasons for omitting them and either he forget about them or implies them, so use them as long as you can;)

Answer (score 0):

I think Hartl states somewhere near the beginning of Chapter 3 that from then on, he will omit the git commit/git add steps from the text for simplicity, but that using them as he directed in the previous chapters is his recommended method for working.